# Write string into initialised blank char array

Tags: c

i have just started learning C and i am confused on how to write a string into a simple char array in C. i understand that C does not have a string data type, and i read that most websites declare string in one of this way

```
char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char greeting[] = "Hello";
```

however what if i have initialized a char array of

```
char greeting[50];
```

and i try to give it a string value.

```
char greeting[50];
greeting = "Zack";
```

i am given a error, why?

Comment: In C, arrays are a const reference. You can't change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` is designed to copy "strings".
Use as follows:

```
char greeting[50];
strcpy(greeting, "Zack");
```

Be aware of potential overruns if the destination isn't big enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use standard function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` that to copy a string in a character array

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char greeting[50];
strcpy( greeting, "Zack" );
```

There are other functions declared in header `<string.h>` that also can be used to copy strings in character arrays. For example

```
memcpy
strncpy
strcat
strncat
```

An example of using `strcat` instead of `strcpy`

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char greeting[50];

greeting[0] = '\0';
strcat( greeting, "Zack" );
```

Arrays have no the assignment operator. So the compiler issues an error for this code snippet

```
char greeting[50];
greeting = "Zack";
```

But there is a trick when you may assign character arrays. To do that you need to enclose a character array in a structure and use a compound literal. For example. Contrary to arrays structures have the assignment operator that performs member-wise copy of structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct A { char greeting[50]; } s;
    s = ( struct A) { "Zack" };

    puts( s.greeting );

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
Zack
```

That this code would be compiled you need a compiler that supports C99.

Answer (score 1):

You use `strcpy()`:

```
char greeting[50];

strcpy(greeting, "Zack");
```

This will copy the four characters and the terminating zero into `greeting`.

Beware that it knows nothing about the available space at `greeting`, so it's perfectly possible to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you're basically trying to assign a string constant to an array. The array `greeting` decays to a pointer, but it's a `char *const` pointer.

You need to use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy the literal.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the folowing code will print "foo":

```
char greeting[50];
if(greeting == &greeting[0]){
    printf("foo");
}
else{
    printf("bar");
}
```

This happens because the variable of the array (*greeting*) contains a pointer to the first element of it (*greeting[0]*).

So, if you asign:

```
greeting = "Zack";
```

You are saying: Let *greeting* have the address of where the literal string *"Zack"* is in the memory.

As changing the address of a array is not allowed, you get an error.

Comment: And that's why you must follow @doctorlove answer to make this assignment

Comment: @user3204469 It is a wrong statement that arrays contain pointers to their first elements.

Comment: @Baldrickk, I understood that the question was: "why is this statement wrong?" not "how to copy a string to an array?". Sorry by my misunderstanding.

Comment: @user3204469 it seems you edited the answer within the grace period and it hadn't updated when I commented.  Looks fine now, though it should say "the array variable (`greeting`) degrades to a pointer to the first element" because as Vlad says, the array doesn't contain a pointer to itself...